# Main function being mysteriously declared somewhere unknown

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

So I literally have the simplest C++ file on the planet, and it won't compile. I can't seem to figure out where main is being defined before, is it in some weird search path? I've searched around and haven't been able to get anything working.

```
#include <iostream>


int main(int argv, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "It worked!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this happens:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -O3
main.cpp:4:31: error: conflicting declaration ‘char** argv’
 int main(int argv, char* argv[]) {
                               ^
main.cpp:4:14: error: ‘argv’ has a previous declaration as ‘int argv’
 int main(int argv, char* argv[]) {
              ^
main.cpp:4:5: warning: ‘int main(int)’ takes only zero or two arguments [-Wmain]
 int main(int argv, char* argv[]) {
     ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: When you are compiling, try something simpler.  Try "gcc main.cpp".

Comment: The guys below saw the issue :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Both your parameters are currently called argv.

Comment: Yeah, I'm an absolute idiot. Sorry I'm working on a python script to manage my Makefiles and I can't believe I glanced over that. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

Main function is not defined anywhere else. The parameters  of the main function have same names. Change them.